# How to rename the second legend?

Tags: r, ggplot2

i have a hard time changing the name of my second legend.
This is my code:

```
ggplot(data = df4, aes(x = sc, y = changes, color = as.factor(pat))) + 
 geom_line(mapping = aes(linetype = nr), alpha = 0.25, size = 0.3) +   
    geom_line(data = result_df4, aes(x = sc, y = changes, color = pat), linetype = "solid", size = 0.6) +   
    xlab(TeX("$SC$")) +   
    ylab("Relative%") + scale_color_manual(values = color_palette4, name = "Mean")
```

The plot can be seen here: [image]

I want to change 'nr' to 'Pattern', and rank the numbers of Pattern accordningly, not 1,10,2,3 and so on. How would i accomplish that?
The plot uses two different data frames.

1. df4: Full Dataset: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3BqH.png
2. result_df4: Contains the mean for all values of changes with pat and sc being the same from df4: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIIDD.png

If anyone has any other ideas on how to make the plot more visual appealing, feel free to post them.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `labs(linetype = "Pattern")`, and set the levels of the factor to get the required order:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df4 <- tribble(
  ~sc, ~changes, ~col, ~nr,
  0, 0.3, "c1", "p10", 
  1, 0.25, "c2", "p10", 
  2, 0.21, "c1", "p10", 
  3, 0.18, "c2", "p10", 
  4, 0.15, "c1", "p2", 
  5, 0.13, "c2", "p2", 
  6, 0.11, "c1", "p2", 
  7, 0.1, "c2", "p2", 
)

lvls <- c("p2", "p10")

df4 |> 
  mutate(nr = factor(nr, levels = lvls)) |> 
  ggplot(aes(sc, changes, color = col)) + 
  geom_line(aes(linetype = nr), alpha = 0.25, linewidth = 0.3) +   
  geom_line(aes(x = sc, y = changes, color = col), linetype = "solid", linewidth = 0.6) +   
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "blue")) +
  labs(x = "SC", y = "Relative %", color = "Mean", linetype = "Pattern")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-06-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>